# Full text search with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How do I do a full text search in Postgres of all columns without preprocessing? I found http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-intro.html I'm not exactly sure what I need to do.

My initial impression is I need to auto concatenate each column (how do I do that? Can't find via Googling) put it in a WHERE and do @@ to_tsquery

This is for https://github.com/timwis/node-soda2-parser/issues/1 I'm not concerned with bad performance

I tried starting with

```
select array_to_string(translate(string_to_array(r::text, ',')::text, '()', '')::text[], ' ')::tsvector FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails as r LIMIT 1
```

But get:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":[\"syntax error in tsvector: \\\"1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 1 1 2 3 3500 5 7007 198 1264 NULL NULL \\\"Answer created by staff\\\" NULL NULL \\\"9/24/2015 16:01\\\" A000198-092415\\\"\"]}","responseJSON":{"error":["syntax error in tsvector: \"1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 1 1 2 3 3500 5 7007 198 1264 NULL NULL \"Answer created by staff\" NULL NULL \"9/24/2015 16:01\" A000198-092415\""]},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * FROM seattle_police_govqa_audit_trails as r WHERE  regexp_replace(array_to_string(translate(string_to_array(r::text, ',')::text, '()', '')::text[], ' '), '[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', 'g')::tsvector @@ 'created'::tsquery = true LIMIT 10
```